# filter specific string in php

Tags: php, string

$var="UseCountry=1
    UseCountryDefault=1
    UseState=1
    UseStateDefault=1
    UseLocality=1
    UseLocalityDefault=1
    cantidad_productos=5
    expireDays=5
    apikey=ABQIAAAAFHktBEXrHnX108wOdzd3aBTupK1kJuoJNBHuh0laPBvYXhjzZxR0qkeXcGC_0Dxf4UMhkR7ZNb04dQ
    distancia=15
    AutoCoord=1
    user_add_locality=0
    SaveContactForm=0
    ShowVoteRating=0
    Listlayout=0
    WidthThumbs=100
    HeightThumbs=75
    WidthImage=640
    HeightImage=480
    ShowImagesSystem=1
    ShowOrderBy=0
    ShowOrderByDefault=0
    ShowOrderDefault=DESC
    SimbolPrice=$
    PositionPrice=0
    FormatPrice=0
    ShowLogoAgent=1
    ShowReferenceInList=1
    ShowCategoryInList=1
    ShowTypeInList=1
    ShowAddressInList=1
    ShowContactLink=1
    ShowMapLink=1
    ShowAddShortListLink=1
    ShowViewPropertiesAgentLink=1
    ThumbsInAccordion=5
    WidthThumbsAccordion=100
    HeightThumbsAccordion=75
    ShowFeaturesInList=1
    ShowAllParentCategory=0
    AmountPanel=
    AmountForRegistered=5
    RegisteredAutoPublish=1
    AmountForAuthor=5
    AmountForEditor=5
    AmountForPublisher=5
    AmountForManager=5
    AmountForAdministrator=5
    AutoPublish=1
    MailAdminPublish=1
    DetailLayout=0
    ActivarTabs=0
    ActivarDescripcion=1
    ActivarDetails=1
    ActivarVideo=1
    ActivarPanoramica=1
    ActivarContactar=1
    ContactMailFormat=1
    ActivarReservas=1
    ActivarMapa=1
    ShowImagesSystemDetail=1
    WidthThumbsDetail=120
    HeightThumbsDetail=90
    idCountryDefault=1
    idStateDefault=1
    ms_country=1
    ms_state=1
    ms_locality=1
    ms_category=1
    ms_Subcategory=1
    ms_type=1
    ms_price=1
    ms_bedrooms=1
    ms_bathrooms=1
    ms_parking=1
    ShowTextSearch=1
    minprice=
    maxprice=
    ms_catradius=1
    idcatradius1=
    idcatradius2=
    ShowTotalResult=1
    md_country=1
    md_state=1
    md_locality=1
    md_category=1
    md_type=1
    showComments=0
    useComment2=0
    useComment3=0
    useComment4=0
    useComment5=0
    AmountMonthsCalendar=3
    StartYearCalendar=2009
    StartMonthCalendar=1
    PeriodOnlyWeeks=0
    PeriodAmount=3
    PeriodStartDay=1
    apikey=ABQIAAAAJ879Hg7OSEKVrRKc2YHjixSmyv5A3ewe40XW2YiIN-ybtu7KLRQiVUIEW3WsL8vOtIeTFIVUXDOAcQ
    ";

in that string only i want `"api==ABQIAAAAJ879Hg7OSEKVrRKc2YHjixSmyv5A3ewe40XW2YiIN-ybtu7KLRQiVUIEW3WsL8vOtIeTFIVUXDOAcQ";`
 plz guide me correctly;

Comment: Please use markdown so that your code is formatted nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

As shamittomar pointed out, the parse_str will not work for this situation, posted the proper regex below.
<del>Given this seems to be a `QUERY STRING`, use the [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/parse_str) function PHP provides.</del>

**UPDATE**

If you want to do it with regex using [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/preg_match) as [powertieke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684496/filter-specific-string-in-php/3684536#3684536) pointed out:

```
preg_match('/apikey=(.*)/', $var, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Interesting, I thought it would work anyways, well I updated the answer and posted the regex used to pull the apikey.

Answer (score 3):

preg_match(); should be right up your alley

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not looking for

```
api==ABQIAAAAJ879Hg7OSEKVrRKc2YHjixSmyv5A3ewe40XW2YiIN-ybtu7KLRQiVUIEW3WsL8vOtIeTFIVUXDOAcQ
```

but you are looking for

```
apikey=ABQIAAAAJ879Hg7OSEKVrRKc2YHjixSmyv5A3ewe40XW2YiIN-ybtu7KLRQiVUIEW3WsL8vOtIeTFIVUXDOAcQ
```

It is important to know if the api-key property always occurs at the end and if the length of the api-key value is always the same. I this is the case you could use the PHP `substr()` function which would be easiest.

If not you would most probably need a regular expression which you can feed to PHPs `preg_match()` function. Something along the lines of `apikey==[a-zA-Z0-9\-]` Which matches an api-key containing a-z in both lowercase and uppercase and also allows for dashes in the key. If you are using the `preg_match()` function you can retrieve the matches (and thus your api-key value).

Answer (score 0):

people are so fast to jump to preg match when this can be done with regular string functions thats faster.

```
$string = '
expireDays=5
apikey=ABQIAAAAFHktBEXrHnX108wOdzd3aBTupK1kJuoJNBHuh0laPBvYXhjzZxR0qkeXcGC_0Dxf4UMhkR7ZNb04dQ
distancia=15
AutoCoord=1';

//test to see what type of line break it is and explode by that.
$parts = (strstr($string,"\r\n") ? explode("\r\n",$string) : explode("\n",$string));

$data = array();
foreach($parts as $part)
{
    $sub = explode("=",trim($part));

    if(!empty($sub[0]) || !empty($sub[1]))
    {
        $data[$sub[0]] = $sub[1];
    }

}
```

and use `$data['apikey']` for your api key, i would also advise you to wrpa in function.

I can bet this is a better way to parse the string and much faster.

```
function ParsemyString($string)
{
    $parts = (strstr($string,"\r\n") ? explode("\r\n",$string) : explode("\n",$string));

    $data = array();
    foreach($parts as $part)
    {
        $sub = explode("=",trim($part));

        if(!empty($sub[0]) || !empty($sub[1]))
        {
            $data[$sub[0]] = $sub[1];
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

$data = ParsemyString($string);
```

Comment: Your EOL check is wrongly implemented because `\n` is part of `\r\n`.

Comment: Speed of development vs Speed of execution... But hey, whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: so you would rather make slow code because it don't take you as long to do :/ idle some ?

Comment: Depends on how much/often and where the code is used. Its always a trade-off. Usually speed of development is preferred (These days)...